# Downgrading Spring Boot App from Java 11 to Java 8

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I've written the spring boot app, basically REST services using: Maven project with Spring boot, spring data Jpa, Spring web, Java version 11. java.version is written in pom.xml. I am also using HttpClient Java 9 or 11(?) class for some web service calls to other providers.

I have the Java SE DK 11 installed on my computer. It is all running nicely, but the problem occurs when I try to run the built Maven package on our Windows Server which has the Java 8 installed.

I tested it with even some small sandbox application using HttpClient, mvn packaged, run it with java -jar packagename.jar It fails because it does not support the desired classes.

My question is, is it possible to compile and build my app written using some Java 9 Lambdas etc, to a jar file that could run on computers that have Java 8 installed? Or the only option is to recode parts of the code to meet the older supported syntax and classes?

Regards

Comment: If you have used specific parts of JDK11 (HttpClient?) it is clear that it can't be run on JDK8 anymore.. The question is why you use httpClient of Java9+ instead of things which Spring Boot provides? And furthermore why using JDK11 is you need to put it on a system which has only JDK8? And No you can't compile JDK9+ code into JDK8 ... If you want to be compatible with JDK8 you have to use JDK8 code only (syntax etc.)...there is no other option...

Comment: Because this is my first backend project and I've made a mistake by not checking the versions on servers running Java. So these options which can be put in pom.xml: (maven-compiler-plugin with source & target) do not help someone recompile code by putting to, lets say target version to 1.8 (Java 8)? There is no such solution for this problem like it is for frontend JS development with Babel which transpiles code to older ES versions?

Comment: If you have a target environment which only provides JRE8 for running your code needs to be compiled for JRE8. JDK11 will compile your code to run on JRE11 that is called backward compatibility. In JS transpilers convert different syntax/code into older ECMA versions which is not the case in Java. Java has backward compatibility. Technically you can use a JDK11 to compile your code to JDK8 but if you use JDK11 things this will not work (--release 8)..If you change source/target to 8 and recompile that will work.

Answer (score 1):

Start by downloading Java 8 JDK  [Link to Download Java 8](https://www.oracle.com/za/java/technologies/javase/javase8-archive-downloads.html) 
 
Set `JAVA_HOME` to the path of the Java 8 JDK ,As Maven will use that value to compile .
Check the current Java and maven on system `mvn -v` and  `java -version` you will see if the right JDK is set in your environment values ,you might want to open a new terminal window to see changes .

Now that Java 8 JDK is set ,Open `pom.xml` and edit the properties tag set version from 11 to 8

```
 <properties>
    <java.version>8</java.version>
</properties>
```

Run `mvn clean` to delete the pre-compiled files and jar files.
Then run `mvn install package`